# Instantiating coins in empty space

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm developing a small Unity2D game and basically I want to check for free space to instantiate two coins. I have set up a coroutine but for some reason it is not instantiating coins as I'm checking if they hit any bounds.

This is my coroutine

```
    private IEnumerator InsCoins(float secondsBetweenEachIns)
{
    while (true)
    {
        float tmp1X = float.Parse(Random.Range(minX, maxX).ToString());
        float tmp1Y = float.Parse(Random.Range(minX, maxX).ToString());
        float tmp2X = float.Parse(Random.Range(minX, maxX).ToString());
        float tmp2Y = float.Parse(Random.Range(minX, maxX).ToString());

        Vector3 ins1 = new Vector3(tmp1X, tmp1Y);
        Vector3 ins2 = new Vector3(tmp2X, tmp2Y);

        int count = GameObject.FindObjectsOfType<GameObject>().Length;
        int arrayCount = 0;
        Bounds[] getBound = new Bounds[count];
        foreach (GameObject go in GameObject.FindObjectsOfType<GameObject>())
        {
            getBound[arrayCount] = go.renderer.bounds;
            arrayCount++;
        } 
        GameObject tmp1 = (GameObject)GameObject.Instantiate(coin, new Vector3(tmp1X, tmp1Y, 0), Quaternion.identity);
        GameObject tmp2 = (GameObject)GameObject.Instantiate(redcoin, new Vector3(tmp2X, tmp2Y, 0), Quaternion.identity);

        foreach (Bounds go in getBound)
        {
            do
            {
                if (go.Intersects(tmp1.renderer.bounds) || go.Intersects(tmp2.renderer.bounds))
                {
                    Destroy(tmp1); Destroy(tmp2);
                }
            } while (!go.Intersects(tmp1.renderer.bounds) && go.Intersects(tmp2.renderer.bounds));
        }
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(secondsBetweenEachIns);
    }
}
```

Any help will be immensely appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you are not calling the coroutine correctly. Where and how are you calling `InsCoins`?

If you want to call this coroutine you've just to call like this:

`StartCoroutine(InsCoins(2.0)); // For InsCoins with 2 sec between each`

Comment: Yes I'm doing that as you said, but nothing is working.

Comment: Maybe the approach of what you're doing is not correct. What do you mean by "I want to check for free space". I understood you want to create two coins when a defined space is not occupied by any gameobject. Is that correct? If you give me more information I could help you to find out a better approach.

Comment: Yes exactly. I have walls which are set as colliders and I do not wants the coins to be instantiated on those walls because else the player would not be able to reach the,. I want the coins to be in free space where no game objects are in the way.

Comment: I'm thinking in one easier solution. Why don't generating random coins and then check if they are hitting a collider. If the generated coins are hitting a collider, you just have to destroy them and generate new ones. This is not the optimal solution but it's an easy one

Comment: It's better to implement one of the API methods which are in the Unity engine API, for example `OnCollisionStay`.

Here you can take a look at what this method implementation does:

[link](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnCollisionStay.html)

This method is called every frame and check if some go is hitting another go (which has to have its colliders defined). In the implementation you can filter if the collision is generated by the coins.

I suggest you to take a deep look to the Unity physics tutorial:

[link](https://unity3d.com/es/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/physics)

Comment: Is it possible I stick with my method? The coins are being generated now since I applied as you told me [instantiate coins first and check later] but still they are hitting the colliders.

Comment: Of course, but I stongly suggest you to implement after checking the API so you can develop maintainable code.

But if you just want it to work, you have to check if the coin collider is hitting the wall one you can check if the coin center is inside the wall collider like this:

`if(wall.collider.bounds.Contains(coinCenterPosition))
{
   Destroy(coin);
}`

Of course you have to replace wall with your wall go name variable and coin with its name variable too.

If it does not work I stringly recomend you to see the tutorials and redesign your cade!

Comment: but that only checks if it is placed inside the collider, I do not want it hitting the collider.